# apply registerForContextMenu in Linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

In below XML file I implemented a ListView:

Here each row consist a ImageButton and a LinearLayout in which two editText is used as a Name and Mobile no
below code shows the implementation of Listview's XML file

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_inner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Name"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_mobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Mobile"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I have to implement two action when i lond press the ImageButton it should show me a contextMenu which it does like below image

`!-- missing image here --!`

and after pressing the gallery it popups the galary to select the particular image on screen.

Now I want to implement that when I long press on right side apart from imagebutton in the right side LinearLayout and it should popup like

`Edit
Delete
Call
Msg`

i write below code for this which gives me null pointer exception to me

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_inner);
layout.setTag(c.getInt(0));
registerForContextMenu(layout);
```

similarly for ImageButton i write

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
registerForContextMenu(ib);
```

this is the `onCreate` Function

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view,
ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) <br>{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    else
    {
        Log.i("Else", "Construct");<br>
        menu.add(2, (Integer) view.getTag(), 0, Edit);<br>
        menu.add(2, (Integer) view.getTag(), 1, Delete);<br>
        menu.add(2, (Integer) view.getTag(), 2, Call);<br>
        menu.add(2, (Integer) view.getTag(), 3, Sms);
    }
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7e7ix35lqetnlmz/Screenshot_2015-07-30-17-58-38.png?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3juae792tmk64lz/Screenshot_2015-07-30-17-58-58.png?dl=0  Please refer above two images this is what i have done i implemented the contxtMenu for ImageButton but unable to do it for my linear layout please help